# Can't get Twitch API stream object

Tags: jquery, api, twitch

This is my script, which I've attempted to put together from researching the questions here and the Twitch API documentation.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/marcusraven86&callback=?", function (data) {

console.log(data);

});
```

All I'm trying to accomplish is to log the object that is returned so I can look through it and see what's there. Instead of a logged object, I get an error in the console with this:

```
GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/marcusraven86&callback=jQuery1113006526092323474586_1435680266323?_=1435680266324
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on? I'm new to the Twitch API, and all I want to do is check out what's returned from my stream.

Comment: The URL you are using is returning a 404 error (does not exist)

Comment: Then I've got to be doing something wrong, because the link without the callback (when used in the navigation bar) shows what I would expect to find in a returned object, but I get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when I just use that in the script.

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/marcusraven86`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/marcusraven86?callback=?', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wu1d6r58/1/)

Comment: Okay, that got it to where I'm now getting a proper object, but it isn't returning the expected properties. Self, Channel, and Stream aren't there. If its looking at my channel properly, it should at least be returning Stream: null, right?

Comment: Found it. I missed the /kraken before /streams.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!